# The "minimum annual compensation" field could use some inline validation

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

The minimum annual compensation on the job match preferences section doesn't save if you include non-numeric data in the text box. For example, "110000" is valid, but "110,000" is not. If you enter an invalid format, you don't get a warning about it, and instead your job match preferences save without the minimum annual compensation.

[image: Minimum annual compensation]

I think it would be helpful to have some client-side validation or a placeholder that shows the expected input format.

Comment: Even better would be to parse the numbers according to the locale the user has stated in their browser, or to not allow non-numerics in the first place.

Comment: Not allowing non-numeric is best. "100,000" is either 10^2 or 10^5 depending on your locale.

Comment: Are those last 3 digits even meaningful?

Comment: @MSalters depending of your local, it could!

Comment: I believe this could be fixed by simply ignoring non numeric characters... when a user presses `,` it just doesn't do anything and instead the digits are grouped 3-by-3 using spaces automatically.

Comment: I'd be curious as to how things like this slip through, wouldn't this be the assumed input format for anyone from US

Comment: @eis I have never used commas when entering a number (for something like this), and I'm from America. I'm quite surprised that some people enter punctuation in a number input.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if some people have entered `110k` without really thinking about it

Answer (score 1):

I've tweaked it so that it doesn't allow non-numeric inputs. It will be included on the next release, it should be a matter of hours.

Thanks for reporting it!

Comment: So the problem was that nobody did any basic QA testing?